# Marionette empty route taking over server response

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I have the following:

```
@App.module "LocationGridApp", (LocationGridApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  API =
    showLocationGrid: ()->
      LocationGridApp.Show.Controller.showLocationGrid(2)

  class LocationGridApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      "" : "showLocationGrid"
    controller: API

  App.on 'before:start', ->
    new LocationGridApp.Router
```

When I access `<url>` I get the `showLocationGrid` to fire off as expected. When I visit `<url>/companies`, `showLocationGrid` is still firing. I was expecting `<url>/companies` to be handled by my server. Is the empty route doing something I'm not expecting?

main_app.js.coffee

```
@App = do(Backbone, Marionette) ->
  Arc = new Marionette.Application

  Arc.addRegions
    container: "#container"

  Arc.on "start", ->
    if Backbone.history
      Backbone.history.start(pushState: false)
  Arc
```

Answer (score 0):

It's up to your server to serve different files depending on the route: if you get the same result for `<url>` and `<url>/companies`, it is that your server answered with the same static files. Nothing in your client-side code can take over your server-side routing. You should probably inspect your server routing settings.

Comment: The server is sending different htlm files at the `/companies` route, it just happens to include the same `js` files that backbone runs on. Even if it were the same content, shouldn't `showLocaitonGrid` not get fired because the route doesn't match?

Comment: I wonder if Backbone router then doesnt set root as being `/companies`, then `/companies` would match the rule `''`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are saying, but any route `/resources`, `/home`, etc will trigger that function. I just chose `/companies` as an example